# Upgrading to Django 1.11.4 ImportError

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm attempting to upgrade Django from 1.10.7 to 1.11.4 with Python 2.7.11. I've run `pip install Django -U` and `python -c "import django; print django.get_version()"` confirms that Django 1.11.4 is installed. However, when I then go to run tests, I get `ImportError: No module named notmigrations`. Does anyone have any advice?

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 25, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/rhw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/rhw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/rhw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 29, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/rhw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/rhw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/rhw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 62, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/rhw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 601, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/rhw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 546, in setup_databases
    self.parallel, **kwargs
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/rhw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 187, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get('TEST', {}).get('SERIALIZE', True),
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/rhw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 69, in create_test_db
    run_syncdb=True,
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/rhw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 130, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/rhw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/rhw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 83, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/rhw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/rhw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/rhw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 203, in build_graph
    self.load_disk()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/rhw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 82, in load_disk
    module = import_module(module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named notmigrations
```

Comment: did you use migrate command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you are using `notmigrations` in your `MIGRATION_MODULES` setting to disable migrations (as described in [this post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/08/19/django-tip-12-disabling-migrations-to-speed-up-unit-tests.html)).

In Django 1.9+, you should simply use `None` instead of a fake module name like `'notmigrations'` ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.9/#migrations)).

Comment: Thanks, but that's only partway there. I found the line `MIGRATION_MODULES = DisableMigrations()` in my settings and changed it to `MIGRATION_MODULES = None`, and now it gives me `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`

Comment: I didn't say to set `MIGRATION_MODULES = None`, I said to replace `'notmigrations' ` with `None`.  Edit your `DisableMigrations` class to return `None` instead of `'notmigrations'`.

Comment: After going on a vacation and then having to play catch up, I finally got to do that and it worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

For Django 2.0 I create setting file as described [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/08/19/django-tip-12-disabling-migrations-to-speed-up-unit-tests.html) with content like:

```
from settings import *

class DisableMigrations(object):
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return True

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return None

MIGRATION_MODULES = DisableMigrations()
```

and run my tests with test newly created setting